# Change amount of Ram and CPU cores in KVM

Tags: virtualization, vps, kvm-virtualization

How can I Change amount of Ram and CPU cores for a virtual machine in KVM that is already created?
Thanks

Comment: IN run-time or with reboot? That would be really good to know BTW.

Comment: +1 - Also would be worth clarifying whether this would be in virt-manager (as referenced in previous question) or from command line.

Comment: Thanks, I think It's easier to change this in reboot and yes I created VMs in virt-manager but command-line is ok.

Comment: you can't change number of cores or amount of RAM on a running kernel.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can edit its `XML` from command-line with:

```
virsh edit name_vhost
```

Then, you only have to search the `<memory>` tag and modify it

Keep in mind that the memory allocation is in kilobytes, so to allocate 512MB of memory, use 512 * 1024, or 524288.

Comment: Really Thanks, Can I increase CPU cores with this method ?

Comment: You should check this out http://www.semanticlab.net/index.php/KVM_increase_CPU_and_RAM_during_runtime ;)

Comment: Is there any other way ? besides what is explaing on semanticlab.net

Comment: -1  because I simply get: "error: unknown command: name_vhost" . Note that I am using the name of my host instead of that literal string. I like Ahmed's answer in any event, more comprehensive.

Comment: @MikeS: It should have been `virsh edit name_vhost`. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Although the answer was broken, it's now fixed. I removed the -1.

Answer (score 32):

For offline configuration:

To increase the number of CPUs:

```
virsh setvcpus <vm_name> <vcpu_count> --config
```

If you get an error that you exceeded the maximum number, first do:

```
virsh setvcpus <vm_name> <vcpu_count> --config --maximum
```

Then repeat the above:

```
virsh setvcpus <vm_name> <vcpu_count> --config
```

To increase the memory size:

```
virsh setmaxmem <vm_name> <memsize> --config
virsh setmem <vm_name> <memsize> --config
```

For online configuration:

You can set the vCPU and memory while the VM is running with `--current` instead of `--config`, but the new numbers has to be within the maximum values already set. You can not set these maximum numbers while the VM is running. You will have to shutdown the VM with `virsh shutdown <vm_name>`, use the above command and start back the VM with `virsh start <vm_name>`.

Answer (score 7):

You can edit the VM settings in `virt-manager` or in cli by changing the XML  in `virsh edit VMNAME`

Answer (score 1):

To increase the maximum amount of memory that can be allocated to the VM you have to increase the maximum memory limit, power off the VM, increase the memory allocated, the start the VM. There's a step-by-step guide here:

http://earlruby.org/2014/05/increase-a-vms-available-memory-with-virsh/

To get more VCPUs you have to edit the virsh XML file and restart the VM. There's a step-by-step guide to do this here:

http://earlruby.org/2014/05/increase-a-vms-vcpu-count-with-virsh/