# Change KVM cpu threads/Cores after Build

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ubuntu-16.04, virsh

So, changing Vcpus and RAM is [easy enough](https://serverfault.com/questions/403561/change-amount-of-ram-and-cpu-cores-in-kvm).  How can I change the number of threads and cores per vcpu in KVM?  I need 1 Vcpu, four cores, and two threads per core.  Barring that, four cpus with two threads each.

That being said, is there any real difference between configuring it this way and just provisioning 8 vcpus?

Host and guest are both Ubuntu 16.04.  Host is running KVM.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the information I was looking for on [this guide](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/mhhaque/entry/how_to_add_resources_cpu_memory_io_in_guest_vm_on_powerkvm?lang=en).

Effectively, you just need to

`virsh edit [domain]`

And edit your `<cpu>` topology to match whatever you need and change your vcpu allocation to match.

I.E:
`<topology sockets=’1’ cores=’4’ threads=’2’/>`